# Upper bound for eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with all entries $0$ or $1$, and with diagonal all $0$'s.  Can you show the eigenvalues are $\leq n-1$?  It seems like this should be true but I can't make any progress.

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the [Gershgorin circle theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).

Comment: Ok thank you I will look at that. Also, Do you know of any theorem which would say all the eigenvalues of such a matrix must be integers? (Is this even true?)

Comment: No, it's not true.  Try $\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 1 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$: eigenvalues are $0, \pm \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using the $\sup$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. $\|x\|=\max_{1\le i\le n}|x_n|$, we then define
$$\|A\|=\max\{\|Ax\|\,:\,\|x\|=1\}$$
It is not difficult to show $\|Ax\|\leq\|A\|\|x\|$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Hence if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $v$, we have
$$|\lambda|\|v\|=\|\lambda v\|=\|Av\|\le\|A\|\|v\|$$
which implies $|\lambda|\le\|A\|$. Now if $\|x\|=1$ then any entry of $Ax$ has absolute value no larger than $n-1$, so it follows that $|\lambda|\le\|A\|\le n-1$.